# Cant Find UploadStringTaskAsync method in WebClient object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

i am trying to use **await** on an UploadStringAsync() (which belongs to System.Net.WebClient) call, so i read i need to use the method UploadStringTaskAsync() instead, but VisualStudio 2012 said the method is not defined on the WebClient class, how can i fix that? Have anyone face the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: Are you targeting fw4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Better yet, use the new [`HttpClient` package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) instead of `WebClient`; it's more `async`-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, i follow your advice and use HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

**WebClient** in Windows Phone 8 does not have **UploadStringTaskAsync** defined, It has **webClient.UploadStringAsync()** which you can use and handle like so

```
void sendWebRequest()
     {
         WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
         String data = "";//data to upload
         String url="";
         webClient.UploadStringCompleted += webClient_UploadStringCompleted;
         webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), data);
     }
     void webClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
     { }
```